# I used the query by nested and want to it in join operation

Tags: mysql

```
emp_id |  emp_name |   referral |
-------+-----------+------------+
    1  |  amit     |    -       |
    2  |  Vinay    |    1       |
    3  |  Himanshu |    1       |
    4  |  Ashu     |    2       |
    5  |  Sikha    |    3       |
    6  |  Vikram   |    3       |
    7  |  Tusharr  |    5       |
    8  |  Senki    |    5       |
```

This is my table and I want the data like tree where I want how much employees are under emp_id 1 and also for emp_id 3.

I'm using nested query to get this and this will be crashed my server because I have more have 5000 data and daily my database increases. This will based on level or like networking. If my db contains 2M data than.

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp_id 
FROM   emp 
WHERE  ( referral IN(SELECT emp_id 
                     FROM   emp 
                     WHERE  referral IN(SELECT emp_id 
                                        FROM   emp 
                                        WHERE  referral IN(SELECT emp_id 
                                                           FROM   emp 
                                                           WHERE  referral = '3' 
                                                          ))) 
          OR referral IN(SELECT emp_id 
                         FROM   emp 
                         WHERE  referral IN(SELECT emp_id 
                                            FROM   emp 
                                            WHERE  referral = '3')) 
          OR referral IN(SELECT emp_id 
                         FROM   emp 
                         WHERE  referral = '3') )
```

This query returns emp_id 5,6,7,8 and if I put referral ='1' then 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

But if lot of data have in database than it crashed the server .

Please suggest another query using join to get 3 levels emp_id.

Comment: please show `SHOW CREATE TABLE emp`, to let us  know if you have any indexes, and which.

Comment: i already mentioned top of question